# Broadcast Reveiver Dual SIM incoming call block

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am using dual, also I am new to android development.
I have written a application for cut all the incoming call. In many blog & forum post I have find that call blocking is not possible for both the dual sim. But its possible for SIM 1.

My code is working for all other single sim phone, but its not working for Dual sim not even SIM 1. Please guide me to fix this issue.

```
try {
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    setResultData(null); // It will terminate the call
    TelephonyManager telephone = (TelephonyManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class c = Class.forName(telephone.getClass().getName());
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    m.setAccessible(true);

    ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephone);
    // telephonyService.silenceRinger();

    telephonyService.endCall();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Call Terminated"+ number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```